# Infragistics UltraWebTree SelectedNode resulting in HttpUnhandledException

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

I'm having a problem with the UltraWebTree component from Infragistics (version 7.1)

For some reason, when I try to access the SelectedNode property (after selecting an item in the list) I'm getting an exception. Here's some more information:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException (0x80004005): Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown. ---> System.Exception:
>   23.428571428571427 is not a valid value for Int32. ---> System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>   at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.Int32Converter.FromString(String value,
>   NumberFormatInfo formatInfo)    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   System.ComponentModel.BaseNumberConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext
>   context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)    at
>   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.ClientStateXmlParser.ProcessXmlData(UltraWebTree
>   webTree, XmlNode xmlNode, Object currentObj, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   ArrayList eventList)    at
>   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.UltraWebTree.ProcessPostData(XmlNode
>   doc)    at
>   Infragistics.WebUI.UltraWebNavigator.UltraWebTree.LoadPostData(String
>   postDataKey, NameValueCollection values)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessPostData(NameValueCollection postData,
>   Boolean fBeforeLoad)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestWithNoAssert(HttpContext context)
>   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   ASP.default_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be caused by the zooming function of Google Chrome.
When the zooming level is not set to 100%, this exception randomly seems to appear.
When going back to zoom level 100%, everything is working fine again.

This is probably fixed in a newer version of the Infragistics component, because the component was built when Google Chrome didn't even exist.

My guess is the user clicks are calculated by coordinates and you end up with doubles instead of integers when the page is zoomed in.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this happens after scrolling when zoom is not 100%, which makes sense with the answer from Breez.